# problem in mysql query with join and limit the time

Tags: mysql

i have this

```
SELECT COUNT(1) cnt, a.auther_id
                            FROM `posts` a 
                                LEFT JOIN users u ON a.auther_id = u.id
                                    GROUP BY a.auther_id
                                        ORDER BY cnt DESC
                                            LIMIT 20
```

its work fine
bu now i want select from posts which added from 1 day tried to use

```
WHERE from_unixtime(post_time) >= SUBDATE(NOW(),1)
```

but its didnot worked
any one have idea

Comment: Can you be more precise than "its didnot worked"? In what way didn't it work? Did you get an error, or did you get the wrong results? What error? What wrong results? What was your complete query?

Comment: What is the data type for the `post_time` column?  Use `DESCRIBE POSTS`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you added the WHERE clause in the wrong place. It should come after the JOIN but before the GROUP BY, like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) cnt, a.auther_id
FROM `posts` a 
LEFT JOIN users u ON a.auther_id = u.id
WHERE from_unixtime(post_time) >= SUBDATE(NOW(),1) 
GROUP BY a.auther_id
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: i think this too iam going to tring